# cut the content of a column before insertion PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a table photos which has two columns (name_photo and code_support) :

[image]

the result I'm looking for :

[image]

I would like to cut the data of the name_photo field which is separated by pipe so here is what I did:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION string_to_rows(text) RETURNS SETOF TEXT AS $$ 
  DECLARE
    elems text[];      
  BEGIN
    elems :=   string_to_array($1, '|');
    FOR i IN array_lower(elems, 1) .. array_upper(elems, 1) LOOP
      RETURN NEXT elems[i];
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
  END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

now how can i use this function to crop my field before inserting into photo table? thank you in advance

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to write a function for this. The built-in `string_to_array` and `unnest()` functions will do what you want:

```
select t.name, p.code_support
from photos p
  cross join unnest(string_to_array(p.nom_photo, '|')) as t(name)
```

`unnest()` turns the elements of an array into rows.

Comment: And how can I create a trigger that inserts? I am a bit lost in logic. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This returns the result you want. I don't understand what a trigger has to do with this?

Comment: In fact I will cut the field for each new insertion in the table

Comment: Then why not simply "cut" the values **before** you insert? And insert multiple rows instead of a delimited value?

Comment: Yes it is a solution but I do not know how to proceed? with a trigger?

Comment: What I'm looking for is that before inserting the field must be cut